# Is the splitting field of $x^3-x^2+1$ over $F_3$ a counterexample of Artin–Schreier theory

Tags: galois-theory

It seems to me that the field $\frac{F_3[x]}{x^3-x^2+1}$ is a counter example of Artin–Schreier theory.

The polynomial $x^3-x^2+1$ is an irreducible polynomial over $F_3$. On the other hand, $x^3-x^2+1$ is a factor of $x^{27}-x$. So the splitting filed of $x^3-x^2+1$ over $F_3$ is a degree 3 cyclic Galois extension over $F_3$. (I calculate the roots of this polynomial. Let $\alpha$ be a root. Then all three roots are $\alpha,\alpha^2-1,-\alpha^2-\alpha+2$.)

However, by Artin–Schreier theory, the only degree 3 extension over $F_3$ should be an Artin–Schreier extension, which the corresponding polynomial should be in the form $x^3-x-a$ for some $a\in F_3$.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Look at $\frac1\alpha$. It satisfies $X^3-X+1$.

Comment: You still need to check if $\Bbb F_3[x]/(x^3-x^2+1)$ is the splitting field of an Artin-Shreier polynomial.

Comment: Thanks. I am still a bit confusion. Does that mean if an extension is isomorphic to an Artin-Shreier extension, then it is an Artin-Shreier extension? The polynomial is not that important?

Comment: That field is a splitting field for *every* cubic irreducible over the ground field.

Answer (score 1):

As others explained in the comments, there is no contradiction. This extension can also be gotten as the splitting field of an Artin-Schreier polynomial.

Surely you have seen something similar when looking at a simpler field extension. Like $x^2-2$ and $(x-1)^2-2$ share the same splitting field over $\Bbb{Q}$. An irreducible polynomial determines a splitting field (up to isomorphism), but not the other way around: the same extension field can be gotten from several polynomials.

- Artin-Schreier theory simply promises that one of the polynomials
  with this splitting field has that special form.
- It should be seen in the same light as the elementary result saying that any quadratic extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ (or any field where $1+1\neq0$) can be gotten by adjoining the square root of some element. Or,
- If a field $K$ contains a primitive root of unity of order $n$, and $L/K$ is a cyclic Galois extension of degree $n$, and then $L=K(\root n\of a)$ for some element $a\in K$ (Kummer's theorem).
- The proofs of both Kummer's theorem and Artin-Schreier theorem rely on Artin's lemma on the independence of characters — another argument emphasizing how these two results are analogues. The difference (and the root cause) being that in a field of characteristic $p$ we cannot have primitive roots of unity of order $p$.